# Loading Excel XML and converting to excel 2003 binary format

Tags: xml, excel, server, interop

I am currently using Excel Interop to load xls files in xml format, and then SaveAs functionality in VB.Net to Save the loaded object to Biff8 xls format. However this can only be done on desktop, if I need to have this done on the server, I would need Microsoft Office installed there, which as per Microsoft is not a recommended solution. Is this possible by any other alternative libraries?

```
        Excel.Application i = new Excel.Application();
        i.DisplayAlerts = false;
        Excel.Workbook w = i.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Temp\\TempXml.xls");
        w.SaveAs("C:\\Temp\\Temp1.xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8);
        i.Workbooks.Close();
        w.Close();
```